# How to reload Nvidia driver, (Nvidia Optimus/multiscreen: How to restart optirun after hibernation/suspend)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, nvidia-optimus, hibernate, bumblebee

I use the following scripts to initialize multiscreen setup:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initializes Nvidia Optimus for multi-screen functionality.

sudo modprobe bbswitch
optirun true
intel-virtual-output
```

But when my machine suspends, it goes back to a single screen. I try to restart by terminating and initializating again. I terminate with the following:

```
sudo kill -15 $xorg_process
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
```

Then I run the initialize script again, but I get the following message:

```
[16929.676769] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

[16929.676811] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Manual testing indicates that this error comes from the `optirun true` command in the initialize script. Is there a way I can reload my second screen after my machine hibernates? (or, more specifically, how to reload the Nvidia driver?)

I am referencing the solution to the Optimus multiscreen monitor issue (for machines with outputs hard-wired to the discrete GPU) found
[here](http://www.unixreich.com/blog/2013/linux-nvidia-optimus-on-thinkpad-w520w530-with-external-monitor-finally-solved/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me on a Thinkpad T520 under arch:

Before suspending:

```
killall Xorg
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo modprobe bbswitch
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< OFF
sudo systemctl stop bumblebeed
```

After resume:

```
sudo rmmod nvidia
sudo modprobe nvidia
sudo modprobe bbswitch
sudo systemctl start bumblebeed
sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<< ON
optirun true
intel-virtual-output
```

Especially reloading the nvidia kernel module seems to do the trick for me here.